# Как скриптом добавить класс (lazyload) к изображению?

Tags: javascript, html, lazyloading

Задача скриптом добавить класс к уже имеющемуся классу в изображении.
Пример:
`<img src="https://site.ru/image.jpg" class="store">` - и не важно какой сейчас класс у разных изображений (они могут быть разные), важно внести туда свой класс `"lazyload"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим пример на весь экран - открываем консоль разработчика - и смотрим что class="num"

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let images = [...document.getElementsByTagName("img")];

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].classList.add("num");
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/28" alt="">
<img src="http://placehold.it/30" alt="">
<img src="http://placehold.it/20" alt="">
<img src="http://placehold.it/26" alt="">
```

Ещё вот так можно

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(i, e) {
  i.classList.add("new");
})
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/30" class="img" alt="">
<img src="http://placehold.it/40" class="img" alt="">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="img" alt="">
```

> **Оба примера добавляют class таким образом**  `<image src="" class="class1 class2">`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Максим а если уже у изображения есть класс, класс num корректно добавится таким образом <img src="image.jpg" class="stuore num">  или так <img src="image.jpg" class="stuore num" class="num">? Второй вариант не подходит

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А какой из вариантов лучше?

Comment: и если нет класса у изображения, класс создастся?

Comment: @Arcadiy  да конечно создастся